# Getting Gregorian date not Hijri date in windows 10

Tags: c#, date, hijri

I use Hijri calendar on my windows 10. I'm working on a C# program and I tried using of `DateTime.Now` to get AD date but it gave me Hijri date.

So, how could I get AD date, not hijri date?

Must I convert Hijri to AD date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` itself is *always* Gregorian - `DateTime.Year` etc will always return the value in the Gregorian calendar.

However, the `ToString` method *will* take into account the default calendar of the culture it's using to format. That culture is (by default) the current thread culture.

The right answer here depends on whether you want to use the current thread culture for other aspects of formatting.

If you want culture-sensitive formatting (because you're displaying this directly to a user), you could clone the culture and set the `DateTimeFormat.Calendar` in the clone to a `GregorianCalendar`, then pass the clone to the `ToString` method.

If you actually want to use culture-invariant formatting (because this is intended to be machine-readable, e.g. in a JSON document) just pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `ToString`.

(If you're actually worried about how it's formatted in the debugger, I'm not sure of the best answer...)